# Finding angle in a system

Tags: geometry

Lets say we have the following drawing:

[image]

This is from a physics exercise but my issue is with the math. I have calculated that $\alpha_3 = 41.8 \text{ degrees}$

How do I now get $\alpha_2$? It is ment to be $45-\alpha_3$ but I don't understand how that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sum of angles in a triangle is equal to $180°$.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

The sum of angles in a triangle is always $180$. In your case, you have $\alpha_2+\alpha_3 + 135= 180$ which means that $\alpha_2=45-\alpha_3$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So how did you find out that the angle is $135$ in the triangle?

Comment: @osk If you extend the three dotted lines, you can create a couple of triangles for which you know the angles. Really basic geometry.

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble to figure it out, I can create a couple of triangles but they don't lead me the right way

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Here's an image of your answer...Feel free to ask if you don't understand anything